# Method to parse expression with SpelExpressionParser that returns different types

Tags: java, spring, parsing, spring-el

I have created a method to calculate an expression which is either a string concatenation or an arithmetic operation. So I wanted to create a method that can return either a String or an Integer. Is there a more elegant and correct way to do that?

```
private static Object calculateExpression(Object object) {
        ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression((String) object);

        if (expression.getValue() instanceof Integer) {
            return expression.getValue();
        } else if (expression.getValue() instanceof String) {
            return expression.getValue();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can process only Strings or Integers");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know what type the expression you passshould be evaluated into you can use generics for that. I would also ask for string instead of object in the parameters. As a SpEL is always a string.

```
private static <T> T calculateExperssion(String expr, Class<T> class) {
    ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression(expr);
    return class.cast(expression.getValue());
}
```

When using this the second parameter will be either `String.class` or `Integer.class`

Answer (score 1):

No, not unless you know the class before calling, then you can use generics as Stav Saad said. Otherwise you have to simply return it and use `instanceof` after returning. Your function may then become.

```
private static Object calculateExpression(String input) {
    ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression(input);
    if (expression.getValue() instanceof Integer || expression.getValue() instanceof String ) {
        return expression.getValue();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can process only Strings or Integers");
}

public static void useCalculate() {
    Object expression = calculateExpression("Test");
    if(expression instanceof String) {
        //Do stringy stuff
    } else if(expression instanceof Integer) {
        //To inty stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, i will add one thing. In your case, if it's string or integer then result will be returned and if the condition is not fullfilled then a `null` will be returned. There is no point to use `instaceof` operator in this case. You can simple return value. `Instanceof` you have to use from where you are calling the function. Here is an example :

```
Expression e = calculateExpression(Object object);
if(e.getValue().instanceof(Integer))
   int variabl = e.getValue();
else if(e.getValue().instanceof(String))
   String s = e.getValue();
```

If you want only evaluation of String and Integers then it would be good test only for cases which can not be handled.

```
if (!(expression.getValue() instanceof Integer) || !(expression.getValue() instanceof Integer)) 

throw someExceptions();
```

\Here it is need because you need to know what kind of value you are getting before assigning it to the variable so `instanceof` operator is made for this case.
So in your case you don't need to check the instance because i guess that Expression is your super class of both Integer and String.